# Some U.S. Tax Questions (CPA Concerns)

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, schedule-d

I tried to do my personal taxes myself with TurboTax this year, but decided my situation was more complicated than I could handle, so filed an extension and decided to engage a CPA.  He missed a few items in his initial draft, so I am naturally checking subsequent drafts very carefully, and have a few concerns.

Because of the pre-work I did in Turbotax, I had something of a preview of the numbers and the information required to complete the forms.  Here are the questionable items:

1. As noted in [this post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30543/how-are-share-awards-and-sales-treated) , I received a share award which resulted in a short term capital loss.  Actually the reason I asked the question is that it was not included in his initial draft (it was one of the things he missed).  He has included this on Schedule D line 1a, but I don't see any details on the actual transaction.
2. Semi-related, Turbotax asked me to fill in individual stock sales with proceeds and cost basis information.  I provided this to him, but don't see the detailed transactions documented anywhere.  Again, it seems to be documented on Schedule D in boxes 1a and 8a.
3. I received a 1099-Q for a 529 distribution for a family member.  It was used for qualified expenses, so should not be taxable.  Turbotax asked me to the beneficiary's name and SSN.  He has not asked for this information, and I don't see anything about the 1099-Q in his draft.
4. I started my own company last year in May, so did not start paying estimated taxes until the Q2 payment.  I believe I paid the correct amounts based on my (possibly flawed) understanding of estimated taxes.  His initial draft had me paying a penalty.  I explained my situation for the year, and his next draft had the penalties removed, with no documentation or explanation.

Do these all seem reasonable, or should I be concerned about these items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He has included this on Schedule D line 1a, but I don't see any
>   details on the actual transaction.

It is reported on [form 8949](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-8949,-Sales-and-Other-Dispositions-of-Capital-Assets). However, if it is fully reported in 1099-B (with cost basis), then you don't have to actually detail every position.

> Turbotax asked me to fill in individual stock sales with proceeds and cost basis information. ... Again, it seems to be documented on Schedule D in boxes 1a and 8a.

See above.

> I received a 1099-Q for a 529 distribution for a family member. It was
>   used for qualified expenses, so should not be taxable.

Then there's nothing to report.

> I believe I paid the correct amounts based on my (possibly flawed) understanding of estimated taxes. His initial draft had me paying a penalty. I explained my situation for the year, and his next draft had the
>   penalties removed, with no documentation or explanation.

IRS assesses the penalty. If you *volunteer* to pay the penalty, you can calculate it yourself and pay with the taxes due. Otherwise - leave it to the IRS to calculate and assess the penalty they deem right and send you a bill. You can then argue with the IRS about that assessment. Many times they don't even bother, if the amounts are small, so I'd suggest going with what the CPA did.